# Swift UiTableViewCell Resets after long press

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer

in my main View Controller I have a button that popups a dialog with two buttons and a tableView. The tableView is being displayed using a custom UIView and the UITableViewCell are also custom. The UITableViewCell consists of a custom checkbox and a UILabel.I'm trying to add a tap gesture to the tableView so that when I click on a row it marks the checkbox. This feature kinda of works but when I press for more then 3 seconds the UITableViewCell resets to this

[UITableViewCell Error ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/te5Q6.png)

I don't know whats causing this error. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code in my ViewController that opens the popup dialog:

```
func locationButtonPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    // Create a custom view controller
    let vc = RadiusViewController(nibName: "RadiusViewController", bundle: nil)
    // Create the dialog
    let popup = PopupDialog(viewController: vc, buttonAlignment: .horizontal, transitionStyle: .bounceDown, gestureDismissal: true)

    // create first button
    let cancelButton = CancelButton(title: "Cancel", height: 60, dismissOnTap: true) {
        print("Popup Canceled")
    }

    // create second button
    let okButton = DefaultButton(title: "Ok", height: 60, dismissOnTap: true) {
        print("Ok button pressed")
    }

    // add buttons to dialog
    popup.addButtons([cancelButton, okButton])

    // present dialog
    self.present(popup, animated: true, completion: nil)

    print("location button pressed")
}
```

Tap Gesture Function in my Custom UIView with the tableView:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ...code

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tableTapped))
    self.tableView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

func tableTapped(tap:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let location = tap.location(in: self.tableView)
    let path = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: location)
    if let indexPathForRow = path {
        self.tableView(self.tableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPathForRow)
        print("Tapped on the table")
    } else {
        // handle tap on empty space below existing rows however you want
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you may need add tap gesture on your tableviewcell, not  the tableview.

Comment: How would i go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to have your ViewController implement the UITableViewDelegate. There is a callback method for `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and in there you can set logic to access your cell's properties, such as the custom checkbox. A tap gesture recognizer is not needed as this is a natively provided function.

[UITableViewDelegate Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate)